# Pivot Table in PSQL

Tags: sql, pivot, psql

I am trying to transform the table below

Current Table

```
Item    Jan Feb Mar Apr  
A   70  3   7   36  
B   4   49  41  74  
C   35  32  54  94  
D   85  58  76  55
```

Desired Table

```
Item    Values  Total  
A   Jan 70  
A   Feb 3  
A   Mar 7  
A   Apr 36  
B   Jan 4  
B   Feb 49  
B   Mar 41  
B   Apr 74  
C   Jan 35  
C   Feb 32  
C   Mar 54  
C   Apr 94  
D   Jan 85  
D   Feb 58  
D   Mar 76  
D   Apr 55
```

I am trying to do this in PSQL and any help would be appreciated. Unfortunately, all my searches show tables going the other way.

Comment: `psql` can be the command line client for Postgres, but it could also mean the procedural language for Firebird. What exactly are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do an "unpivot".  The easiest way is with `union all`:

```
select item, 'Jan' as values, Jan as Total
from table t
union all
select item, 'Feb' as values, Feb as Total
from table t
union all
select item, 'Mar' as values, Mar as Total
from table t
union all
select item, 'Apr' as values, Apr as Total
from table t;
```

If your table is large and you are concerned about performance, the following may have better performance characteristics:

```
select t.item, n.values,
       (case when n.values = 'Jan' then Jan
             when n.values = 'Feb' then Feb
             when n.values = 'Mar' then Mar
             when n.values = 'Apr' then Apr
        end) as Total
from table t cross join
     (select 'Jan' as values from dual union all select 'Feb' from dual union all
      select 'Mar' from dual union all select 'Apr' from dual
     ) n ;
```

Note:  I used `from dual` in the definition for `n` because I read the tag as "plsql".  This will also work in many databases:

```
from table t cross join
     (select 'Jan' as values union all select 'Feb' union all
      select 'Mar' union all select 'Apr'
     ) n ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
create table as  new_table
select item, 'Jan' as val, jan as total from old_table;
union all
select item, 'Jan' as val,  feb as total from old_table;
union all
select item, 'Jan' as val,  mar as total from old_table;
union all
select item, 'Jan' as val,  apr as total from old_table;
```